# DRF reverse action url from viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets

I have an issue reversing the URL of **ViewSet** actions in the DRF
my codes are below, I try some methods to reverse URLs but also you can see it's not working for me

*view.py*

```
class Device_API(ViewSet):
   
    def list(self, request) -> Response:
        ...

    def update(self, request, pk) -> Response:
        ...
    
    def create(self, request) -> Union[Response, Http404]:
        ...

    
    def destroy(self, request, pk) -> Union[Response, None]:
        ...

    
    @ action(
        detail=False,
        methods=["GET"],
        url_path=r"filter/(?P<type>\w+)",
        url_name="filter_type",
    )
    def filter(self, request, type) -> Union[Response, Http404]:
        ...

    @ action(detail=True, methods=["GET"], url_name="data")
    def data(self, request, pk) -> Union[Response, Http404]:
        ...
```

*urls.py*

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter, SimpleRouter
from .views import Device_API

Router = DefaultRouter()
app_name = "api"

Router.register("device", Device_API, basename="Device")
urlpatterns = Router.urls
```

and I try to reverse the URL like below but I get an error

```
view = Device_API()
        view.basename = "Device"
        view.request = None
        url = view.reverse_action('filter')
```

or

```
url = reverse('Device-filter')
```

*Error*

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'Device-filter' not found. 'Device-filter' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I and also tried this

```
url = reverse('api:Device-filter')
```

*Error*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nova/Documents/projects/webserver/ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 71, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
KeyError: 'api'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nova/Documents/projects/webserver/webserver-iot/WEB_SERVER/tests/test_api_v1.py", line 63, in test_test
    url = reverse('api:Device-list')
  File "/home/nova/Documents/projects/webserver/ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 82, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'api' is not a registered namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding a *namespace* into URLs in **urls.py** in settings like this

*urls.py*

```
path("", include("my_app.urls", "API")),
```

I could retrieve URLs by these methods

`from django.urls import reverse`
*or*
`from rest_framework.reverse import reverse`

```
url = reverse("API:Device-list") 
#              {basenam}-method-name
```

and you can set the basename for your view in this way

*my_app/urls.py*

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import My_View

Router = DefaultRouter()
Router.register("device", Device_API, basename="Device")
urlpatterns = Router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url name is `filter_type`

```
@ action(
        detail=False,
        methods=["GET"],
        url_path=r"filter/(?P<type>\w+)",
        url_name="filter_type",
    )
```

So try:

```
url = reverse('api:Device-filter_type')
or
url = reverse('api:Device-filter-type')
```

Comment: yes, it's just an example but doesn't work Device-filter_type or anything else even default methods like list or destroy ...